# How to change JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data like this

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "node": {
                "title": "Kieu Oanh",
                "Image": "",
                "view_node": "view",
                "link": "drupal_dev/content/kieu-oanh"
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "title": "Kieu Oanh",
                "Image": "",
                "view_node": "view",
                "link": "drupal_dev/content/kieu-oanh"
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

Now I want to convert it to

```
var rel_data = [{
    "title": "asa",
    "Image": "sasa",
    "view_node": "sajsjla"
}, {
    "title": "asa",
    "Image": "sasa",
    "view_node": "sajsjla"
}]
```

And This is my code to convert data to rel_data

```
data = data.nodes;
for (d in data) {
    rel_data[d].title = data[d].node.title;
    rel_data[d].image = data[d].node.Image;
}
for (d in rel_data) {
    alert(rel_data[d].title);
}
```

But it does not seem to work, is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: This does not have anything particular to do with JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to edit objects which aren't there yet.

The first thing you do is access `rel_data` while there is no `rel_data` yet. The second thing you do is that you change properties of array elements which do not exist.

Your code should be the following to work:

```
 data = data.nodes;
 rel_data = new Array(); // Create rel_data
 for(d in data) {
        rel_data[d] = new Object(); // Create array element
        rel_data[d].title= data[d].node.title;
        rel_data[d].image= data[d].node.Image;
 }

 for(d in rel_data) {
        alert(rel_data[d].title);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `map` instead of a `for` loop (for generating the new array, you'd want one for the `alert()`)

```
var rel_Data = data.nodes.map(function(item) { 
    return { 
       "title": item.node.title, 
       "Image": item.node.Image, 
       "view_node": item.node.view_node 
    }; 
});
```